# how to fix "The type or namespace name 'xmleditor' does not exist in the namespace microsoft.visualstudio (are you missing an assembly reference ?)"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When i import My visual studio extension project created in Visual studio 2017 in visual studio 2019 preview i get many xml errors like below.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.XmlEditor;


The type or namespace name ‘XmlEditor’ does not exist in the namespace microsoft.visualstudio (are you missing an assembly reference ?)
```

Can anyone suggest how this can be resolved?

Comment: Are you using any VS2017-specific assemblies that need to be upgraded to VS2019?

Comment: It worked after removing the existing reference and adding it again manually, thanks